# What game did these pawns go to?

Tags: identify-this-game

Vintage unidentifiable Hard plastic game pieces 8 short 4 medium 1 large in both blue and red. [image]

Answer (score 11):

They look like they belong to [Smess: The Ninny's Chess](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1289/all-kings-men).

Comment: You did beat me by a couple of minutes - these version of figures were from a Parker Bros. edition from the 1970's (in Germany 1972 under the name *Schach dem Schlaukopf*